# Can not send transaction from client

Tags: solana-program, native-programs

In my project, I'm using native Solana to create a contract. It is a basic program for users to enter their product info. I successfully built and deployed the contract but when I try to send a transaction from a client to enter product data I get an error:  
`Err` value: Custom { kind: InvalidInput, error: "Unexpected length of input" }

index.ts (client)

```
const productInstructionLayout = borsh.struct([
    borsh.u8('variant'),
    borsh.str('name'),
    borsh.u32('price'),
    borsh.u32('quantity'),
])

async function sendTestProductInfo(signer: web3.Keypair, programId: web3.PublicKey, connection: web3.Connection) {
    let buffer = Buffer.alloc(1000)
    const productName = `Shirt${Math.random()*100}`
    productInstructionLayout.encode(
        {
            variant: 0,
            name: productName,
            price: 200,
            quantity: 2000,
        },
        buffer
    )

    buffer = buffer.slice(0, productInstructionLayout.getSpan(buffer))
    console.log(buffer.length)
    const [pda] = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
        [signer.publicKey.toBuffer(), Buffer.from(productName)],
        programId
    )

    console.log("PDA is:", pda.toBase58())

    const transaction = new web3.Transaction()
    
    const instruction = new web3.TransactionInstruction({
        programId: programId,
        data: buffer,
        keys: [
            {
                pubkey: signer.publicKey,
                isSigner: true,
                isWritable: false
            },
            {
                pubkey: pda,
                isSigner: false,
                isWritable: true
            },
            {
                pubkey: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
                isSigner: false,
                isWritable: false
            }
        ]
    })

    transaction.add(instruction)
    const tx = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [signer])
}
```

instruction.rs

```
use borsh::BorshDeserialize;
use solana_program::program_error::ProgramError;
pub enum ProductInstruction {
    AddProductData {
        name: String,
        price: u32,
        quantity: u32,
    },
    UpdateProductData {
        name: String,
        price: u32,
        quantity: u32,
    },
    DeleteProductData {
        name: String,
    },
}

#[derive(BorshDeserialize)]
struct ProductPayload {
    name: String,
    price: u32,
    quantity: u32,
}

impl ProductInstruction {
    pub fn unpack(input: &[u8]) -> Result<Self, ProgramError> {
        let (&variant, rest) = input
            .split_first()
            .ok_or(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData)?;
        let payload = ProductPayload::try_from_slice(rest).unwrap();
        Ok(match variant {
            0 => Self::AddProductData {
                name: payload.name,
                price: payload.price,
                quantity: payload.quantity,
            },
            1 => Self::UpdateProductData {
                name: payload.name,
                price: payload.price,
                quantity: payload.quantity,
            },
            2 => Self::DeleteProductData { name: payload.name },
            _ => return Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData),
        })
    }
}
```

processor.rs

```
pub fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    let instruction = ProductInstruction::unpack(instruction_data)?;
    match instruction {
        ProductInstruction::AddProductData {
            name,
            price,
            quantity,
        } => add_product_data(program_id, accounts, name, price, quantity),
        ProductInstruction::UpdateProductData {
            name,
            price,
            quantity,
        } => update_product_data(program_id, accounts, name, price, quantity),
        ProductInstruction::DeleteProductData { name } => {
            delete_product_data(program_id, accounts, name)
        }
    }
}
pub fn add_product_data(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    name: String,
    price: u32,
    quantity: u32,
) -> ProgramResult {
    let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

    let initializer = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let pda_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let system_program = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;

    if !initializer.is_signer {
        msg!("Missing required signature");
        return Err(ProgramError::MissingRequiredSignature)
    }
    
    let (pda, bump_seed) = Pubkey::find_program_address(
        &[initializer.key.as_ref(), name.as_bytes().as_ref()],
        program_id,
    );

    if pda != *pda_account.key {
        msg!("Invalid seeds for PDA");
        return Err(ProgramError::InvalidArgument)
    }
    
    let account_len: usize = 1000;
    let total_len: usize = 1 + (4 + name.len()) + 32 + 32;
    if total_len > 1000 {
        msg!("Data length is larger than 1000 bytes");
        return Err(ReviewError::InvalidDataLength.into())
    }
    let rent = Rent::get()?;
    let rent_lamports = rent.minimum_balance(account_len);

    invoke_signed(
        &system_instruction::create_account(
            initializer.key,
            pda_account.key,
            rent_lamports,
            account_len.try_into().unwrap(),
            program_id,
        ),
        &[
            initializer.clone(),
            pda_account.clone(),
            system_program.clone(),
        ],
        &[&[
            initializer.key.as_ref(),
            name.as_bytes().as_ref(),
            &[bump_seed],
        ]],
    )?;

    let mut product_data =
        try_from_slice_unchecked::<ProductAccountState>(&pda_account.data.borrow()).unwrap();
    product_data.name = name;
    product_data.price = price;
    product_data.quantity = quantity;
    product_data.is_initialized = true;

    product_data.serialize(&mut &mut pda_account.data.borrow_mut()[..])?;
    Ok(())
}
```

It seems that the error has to do with instruction_data. But I am not sure where it comes from since I matched the layout on my client with the contract payload. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're forgetting to reserve the first element of the buffer for the instruction representation. `buffer[0]` should be set to `0` to represent `AddProductData`, while the rest of your arguments are serialized into the buffer starting from `[1..]`.

Comment: You're highly welcome